# Find the domain and range, then sketch the domain in the xy-plane for the following function: $h(x,y)=x^{4}e^{3xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I found the domain to be every real number on the cartesian plane (2D).

I found the range as $(0,\infty)$. I'm sure that this is correct but I was told that it should be inclusive to $0$, so $[0,\infty)$. Is this true? and why if yes.

Also for the sketch of the domain I will know how to do it if the second point is answered. Just unsure if the range is inclusive to $0$ or not.

Comment: What is the value of $h(0,y)$?

Comment: The value would be 0

Comment: That should answer your questions regarding the range.

Comment: So since it has an actual value at 0, the range will be inclusive...
[0,infinity)? I just thought that since the range of the function y=e^x is (0,infinity) that it would be the same case for this